# What are various ways, as per Scriptures, by which we lose our Punya:Good Merits?

Tags: scripture, karma, sin, punyam

It is said that if we refuse to donate someone who has come to ask for donations, then our Punya is lost.

What are other ways, as per Scriptures, which make us lose Good Virtues?

Comment: if you point out the fault of others, half of that fault's papa comes to you if they actually did that fault. if they did not even commit a fault and we speak bad of them, the full papa of that fault comes to us. In Yaksha Prashnam, Yudhistira tells what makes Brahmins similar to fools - it is parivada - pointing out the faults of others. Chanakya also says - bees are drawn to honey, flies are drawn to waste. similarly high-souled people look at good in others, while debased people look at faults of others.

Comment: @ram which scripture says your first point?

Comment: @TheDestroyer, i don't know, probably one of the dharma shastra smritis. I heard it in upanyasam by swami from unbroken lineage of vaishnava sampradaya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be many ways of doing so. Here are few of them from the **Atri Smriti:**

> > To cleanse the teeth with a finger, to eat unmixed salt, and to eat
> >     earth is equally sinful like eating beef. (310)
>
> [To live under] the shade of a Kapithva-tree during the day, [to take] curd in the night,[to live] under the shade of a Sami-tree, to use a cotton-reed for cleaning the teeth, robs even Vishnu's prosperity (311).
>
> **The Sun [when seen at the rising], the wind [of the cremation ground], the water on the finger-nails, the water in a pitcher touched by a cloth at the time of bathing, the dust of a broomstick, and water sprinkling from the hairs, destroy the virtue acquired in the day**. (312)

All the above methods are effective ways of losing punyas specially the ones highlighted. :D

Comment: I could have agreed with the answer. But Aghori AKA Rohit Singh Rathore says- Smriti are not to be followed now.

Comment: @AnuragSingh But there is one Smriti which says that it is applicable specially in Kali Yuga.